# Making Leaflet tileLayer grid starts at specified lat lon

Tags: leaflet, wms, tiles, extents

My app needs to show a map within a box defined by

```
    const corner1 = L.latLng(5.21244812011719, -96.5979537963867);
    const corner2 = L.latLng(34.086555480957, -55.4220504760742);

    const map = L.map(el,
      {
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
        center: [19.6875, -76.201171875],
        zoom: 3.5,
        maxBounds: new L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2),
      });
    L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/wms?", {
        layers: 'xxx',
        tileSize: 700,
        transparent: true,
        maxBounds: new L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2),
        bounds: new L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2)
      }).addTo(map)
```

The thing is that the layer is requesting the tiles starting outside the borders defined (for example, this request was made http://localhost:8080/wms?&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=Mano%3AT22&styles=&format=image%2Fjpeg&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&maxBounds=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&time=2018-05-02T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&width=700&height=700&srs=EPSG%3A4326&bbox=-87.71484375,28.4765625,-56.953125,59.23828125 the bbox was **-87.71484375, 28.4765625, -56.953125, 59.23828125**, this contains the corners defined by me but is not optimal as it is requesting a map area that is not going to be seen on my app)

I need that leaflet request tiles that do not exceed the corners defined.

How can I archieve that?